# Android : Store data in App when App is killed / Re-launched

Tags: android, caching, android-activity

Data store in Android app :i am new to Android  &  I have a settings Activity where I have country and state which are a mandatory option to use the app.When user choose the country and state then he can do certain actions based his choice.
    The issue here is that when he kills the app the data gets removed and the user has to choose the country / state again and again.

```
Below is the code for Settings.java where there is a number picker for both country and state
```

Where I have taken Number pickers to choose data now when user chooses once he has to choose each time he relaunched the app.Once the app is killed all settings are reset.

Settings.java

```
package com.app.info.app

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.app.info.app.Model.Country;
import com.app.info.app.Singleton.BigBoss;

public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    //Country Picker
        final NumberPicker array1 =    
        (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.countrypicker);
        array1.setMinValue(0);
        array1.setMaxValue(BigBoss.getInstance().countries.length-1);
        array1.setDisplayedValues(BigBoss.getInstance().getCountryNames());
        array1.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        array1.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        //Tip picker where user choose the desired Tipping
        NumberPicker statepick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.statepicker);
        statepick.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        statepick.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

     //Tip picker
        NumberPicker tippick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.tippicker);
        tippick.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "5%", "10%", "15%","20%","25%" } );
        tippick.setMinValue(1);// restricted number to minimum value i.e 1
        tippick.setMaxValue(5);// restricked number to maximum value i.e. 31
        tippick.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        tippick.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

    }

        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        if (picker.getId() == R.id.countrypicker) {
            Country selectedCountry = BigBoss.getInstance().countries[newVal];
            BigBoss.getInstance().currentCountrySelected = selectedCountry;
        }            // Here I am using the choosed country for some calculations
    } 
        public void countryClicked(View v) {
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.countrypicker);
        NumberPicker statepick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.statepicker);
        NumberPicker tippick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.tippicker);
        TextView countrytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countryval);
        TextView statetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stateval);
        TextView tiptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tipval);
        statepick.setVisibility((View.GONE));
        tippick.setVisibility((View.GONE));
        if(np.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            np.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            np.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Hiding the picker when one is choosed
        }

    }


        public void stateClicked(View v) {

        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.countrypicker);

        NumberPicker statepick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.statepicker);

        statepick.setMinValue(0);
        String name ="India" ;
        if (BigBoss.getInstance().currentCountrySelected != null) {
            name = BigBoss.getInstance().currentCountrySelected.name;
        }
        statepick.setMaxValue(BigBoss.getInstance().getStateNamesForCountry(name).length-1);
        statepick.setDisplayedValues(BigBoss.getInstance().getStateNamesForCountry(name));  // Get selected Country Above

        NumberPicker tippick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.tippicker);
        np.setVisibility((View.GONE));
        tippick.setVisibility((View.GONE));

        if(statepick.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            statepick.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            statepick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // Setting the visibility of elements 
        }

    }

        public void tipClicked(View v) {
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.countrypicker);

        NumberPicker statepick =(NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.statepicker);

        NumberPicker tippick = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.tippicker);
        np.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        statepick.setVisibility((View.GONE));
        if(tippick.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){

            tippick.setVisibility((View.GONE));
        } else {
            tippick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }


        public void aboutUsclicked(View v)
    {

        Intent aboutus1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), AboutUs.class);
        startActivity(aboutus1);

    }


    public void feedBackclick(View v)
    {

        Intent feed1 = new Intent(v.getContext(), FeedBack.class);
        startActivity(feed1);

    }

    public void logout(View v) {
   TextView logout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logout);

    // Logout Button Click Listener
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Logout current userParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            ParseUser.logOut();

            ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            currentUser.setEmail("");
            currentUser.setPassword("");
            currentUser.setUsername("");

            Intent homebk = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homebk);




        }
    });

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    }
}
```

//This is how I am choosing items from Picker I need to store them Locally so that on Relaunch there is not hassle to re choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use sharedpreferences Class.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

I hope this solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial on shared prefrences [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).Shared Prefrences are used to store small amounts of user data like settings information.  You can also use a prefrence fragment check the tutorial [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment).